# Visual Studio Multiple Date parsing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

My firstdayofweek is my @startdate

Here is my available values expression for my @enddate

```
=Dateadd("d",6,Parameters!FirstDayOfWeek.Value(0))
```

if I select Multiple @startdates, the report returns only one Enddate. I need it for each startdate selected.

I get enddates for each of them based off my expression.

Comment: This is SSRS question?

Comment: @JamesZ yes it is 
why is it being spam downvoted 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450620/ssrs-data-fetch-and-email

Comment: @JamesZ i have found 9 other ssrs questions that havent been downvoted why was mine

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, so I can only guess, but would you really understand you own question without any background knowledge? At least I still don't know what you're really asking. Also, your question doesn't mention SSRS at all, it said "Vual Studio", which at least now is fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Worked it out without your help instead of setting the default date as the first date i just made my second date depend on it

```
select distinct
CAST(lastDayOfWeek AS DATE) as lastDayOfWeek 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Calendar] 
where LastDayOfWeek  >= '01-12-2014'
and dateadd(DAY,6,Firstdayofweek) =LastDayOfWeek 
and FirstDayOfWeek in (@FirstDayOfWeek)
order by 1 desc
```