# SSRS data fetch and email

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to know how can we send automatically email of the 'select' query results of User database with sql server. As i have to send few reports on daily basis to HO for as per status reports.
Kindly help me through..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Subscriptions and Delivery part of SSRS. Link here -  [Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms159762.aspx)
In delivery scenarios look for **E-mail**. Also if you are sending those reports to a fixed HO then normal **standard subscriptions** will do for you, else if your HO changes based on sql query then look for **data-driven subscriptions**.